# Login page error - dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error on the login page when I log out.

> ValueError at /accounts/login/
>
> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

I do not know why I get this error because I've never had such an error before. What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'register',
 'customer',
 'financial_analysis',
 'ocr',
 'core',
 'approvals',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor',
 'rest_framework',
 'requests',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'django_filters',
 'activity_log',
 'djmoney',
 'djmoney.contrib.exchange',
 'mathfilters',
 'bootstrap3',
 'phone_field']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 168, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 244, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

**register/urls.py**

```py
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.urls import path, include
    from CreditReviewBot import settings
    from . import views
    from .views import update_user
    
    
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
        path('', views.home, name='home'),
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        url(r'^accounts/(?P<id>\d+)/update/$', update_user, name="update"),
            
                  ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'approvals.views.approval_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Show the `TEMPLATES` variable in your `settings.py`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I added it.

Comment: Show the code for `approvals.views.approval_context_processor`

Comment: Oh, I added @login_required to context processor... I delete it and it works! thank you